# gitextensions install fails on windows 7 with invald short file name

Tags: git, windows-7, git-extensions

Installing a recent gitextensions on a windows 7 machine gives me
an "`invalid short file name username.user`".

Installing as a different user, even as local admin works, but the extensions work only when I am logged on as this user.

As normal user, I can start the exe and it works fine, but the explorer integration and VS plugins don't work at all (no reaction to clicks).

Answer (score 0):

This is not limited to [gitextensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), but can affect any installer having to deal with [special character in the installation path](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7185515#7185515) or in the username.

See for instance [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2690584).

> > I'm getting an error (installed in Dutch language) "`u.sername` is an invalid short filename" where `u.sername` is the user logged in.
>
> I saw a somewhat similar problem in the Flash Player forum, when a username contained a dot.  They created an additional profile (same username, but with the dot omitted), and everything worked fine.

Comment: thanks, but I tried with local admin, called administrator, no dots there, the installer works, but the gitextensions does not.

Comment: @Git: it doesn't work when you are using it as local admin? or as you?

Comment: I tried several dummy users and the local admin, it works as long as I'm logged in as the same user I installed it. Then back as normal user, the explorer integration and plugin does nothing. no reaction, no error message.

Comment: @Git: I thought so: it must install its shell extension in HKLU (Local User), which differs from the account used for the installation and the final account used for daily operations with gitextensions.

Answer (score 0):

so there is no solution for this one? 
or can the fact that it registers to HKLU help a possible
workaround?

Comment: You shouldn't post that question as an "answer", rather as a comment. I have no immediate solution, other than temporary grant local admin rights to that user in case it make the installation works, or to examine why this particular account has a problem (special character or dot). As you saw, other (dummy) accounts work well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. the problematic account has a dot in it, but this is a standard here for the account names. so gitextensions won't work for me anymore.